# Legacy Oracle RDB needs a Web Application Front End for CRUD

Tags: oracle, web, plone, zope

I am trying to figure out the best approach for rapidly building a web app to do CRUD on an existing Oracle RDB.  I would also like to use it to build other web apps that would be based on the data stored in the RDB.  After watching a very convincing video called "Better Web Application Framework", Zope / Plone with Python looked pretty good.  The problem is that I have never built a web app so I am looking for suggestions on the path forward.

Will Zope / Plone / Python get the job done?  Do I need something else entirely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plone is a Web CMS built on an object database, so unless what you are building fits into that mould I would not really recommend it. You're likely to have more success with either [Django](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) or [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) with [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org). Django is more opinionated whereas Pyramid and SQLAlchemy is more flexible.

If you were already using Plone for other things and wanted to integrate some RDB content into the site and make use of Plone's workflow capabilities then [collective.tin](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/creating-sql-content-types-with-collective.tin/tutorial-all-pages) might be interesting, but I never got around to making a release and it is more of a curiosity at this point.